# Error with heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, dbmigrate

I am trying to run the command on Heroku

Heroku run `rake db:migrate`

but I get the error:

```
Migrating to AddNameToUsers (20130320002032)
== AddNameToUsers: migrating =================================================
-- add_column(:users, :name, :string)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "name" character varying(255)
```

This might have to do with the fact that I had some issues with the migration files on my local server. I managed to work around it and had to delete one of the files, but I worry that I might have deleted something I need that hadn't been migrated to heroku's database?

my github for the account is https://github.com/jeremybelcher/omrails

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your previous migrations are missing.

You can do:

```
rake db:create
rake db:schema:load
rake db:migrate
```

Which will recreate your database based on your `schema.rb` file.